# How to best add HUGE amount of data to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am reading a long text file with currently round about 900.000 lines (log files). I am then filling a DataTable object with the data and until then everything is fine. But when assigning the huge DataTable object to the DataGridView.DataSource it takes ~ 10 minutes until the application is responsive again and the DataGridView shows the data. The same happens if I load the data to the DataGridView directly without a DataTable object. Is there a better way to work with this huge amount of data and a DataGridView?

Comment: Can you share your current code? It's going to be easier to answer your question if we can see how you approached the problem

Comment: winforms/wpf grid? asp.net grid? Have you considered paging? You should consider that presenting the user that amount of data will probably make them get lost trying to find something.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by luck. I read somewhere that it happens if you use the AutoSizeColums property. So I made sure to have it disabled. But within my code I just found "dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;" right before the data table is assigned as the DataSource. So after each line it added to the DataGridView it started to resize the columns -_- now with disabling it completely the whole process lasts around < 10 seconds. So I consider this solved :)

@bradbury
What else could I use to work with this amount of data?

Comment: @Henning Paging data, allow users to sort it, filter it using different search criteria, whatever allows you not to present the user  one million rows to navigate until they find whatever they want. It will have an extra developing, but users probably would like it. If posible you could ask them what  search criteria do they usually do, that would help them be faster searching.

Comment: @bradbury9 Yeah I was going to implement that anyway :) thinks like "show me this problem and +- 50 lines" and so on. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Brad: Point taken, comment removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you need to enable "virtual mode". This isn't entirely trivial, as you need to provide the code to provide cell values on-demand (rather than filling everything in advance), but it isn't horrendous either. [Here's a complete walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control) in the Microsoft docs.

However, from a UX perspective, maybe a better solution is to make it such that you *don't need to display nearly a million lines in a grid*. That isn't a useful user experience, in most cases.

Comment: +1 on the 'however'.  Displaying this number of rows on any user interface is a terrible user experience.